# SESSIONID injection for basic authentication requests

Tags: spring-security

I have a Spring-cloud based micro-services application. I also have an API gateway in front of all these services.

I need to support two types of clients.

One of them can call my application using an authorization token (by calling /authorize for example). The token is basically the SESSION ID. All the servers share the session by using Spring Session Redis.

The second client can only send me http basic authentication (user:pass as authorization header).

In the case of the second client, I need to check if the user is already authenticated and has an active session in redis. I added filter before BasicAuthenticationFilter in my security configuration to check that.

If the user has an active session, I'm putting the SESSIONID in the header, and removing the authorization header from the request (I'm using a custom HttpServletRequest wrapper for that). My purpose was that from that point on, Spring will manage the request in the downstream micro-services as if it was sent with a SESSIONID. The reason for that is to avoid a very long login time (more than 1 second).

Here’s my issue: when spring checks if the SESSIONID exists, it checks the original request which doesnt have any sessionId.

Security configuration:

```
@Resource
    @Qualifier("sessions")
    private Map<String, String> sessions;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("httpSessionStrategy")
    HttpSessionStrategy sessionStrategy;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //      // @formatter:off

    http
    .addFilterBefore(setSessionIdInHeader(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .sessionManagement()
    .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(restEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Server",""))
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(restEntryPoint())
    .and()  
    .logout().addLogoutHandler(clearTicketOnLogoutHandler())
    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login", "/").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).denyAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD).denyAll()  
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .addFilterAfter(ticketValidationFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(changePasswordFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)  
    .addFilterAfter(httpPolutionFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
    .addFilterAfter(saveSessionId(), SessionManagementFilter.class);

    // @formatter:on
}
```

Filter to add header to request:

```
private Filter setSessionIdInHeader(){
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {         
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                Jedis jedis = null;
                String authorization = request.getHeader("authorization");
                String sessionId = null;
                if (authorization != null){   
                    if (sessions.get(authorization) != null){   //user already authenticated
                        sessionId = sessions.get(authorization);
                        jedis = getJedisPool().getResource();
                        if (jedis.hgetAll("spring:session:sessions:"+sessionId) != null){  //session alive in redis
                            log.info("session :"+ sessionId +" exists in redis");
                            HeaderMapRequestWrapper wrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(request); 
                            wrapper.addHeader("TOKEN", sessionId);
                            wrapper.addHeader("mock_authorization", authorization);

                            filterChain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
                        }
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }
```

Change header name of SESSIONID:

```
@Bean
    public HeaderHttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy(){
        HeaderHttpSessionStrategy headerHttpSessionStrategy = new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
        headerHttpSessionStrategy.setHeaderName("TOKEN");
        return headerHttpSessionStrategy;
    }



private Filter saveSessionId() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {         
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
                if(request.getHeader("authorization") != null){
                    sessions.put(request.getHeader("authorization"), request.getSession().getId());
                }else{
                    sessions.put(request.getHeader("mock_authorization"), request.getSession().getId());
                }

            }
        };
    }
```